# Running app on real android phone error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made a sample **app** with an **EditBox** and a **Button** then i tried to run it with a real **mobile phone** and after installing the **APK** on the phone the **default screen** of new project (just **HelloWorld** Text inside) i restarted **Android Studio** and tried to tun the project again but still having the same problem.

Comment: And what is the issue exactly?

Comment: What does `adb logcat` say?

Comment: i want to run the APK i made but it opened the APK with the default screen not including what i did

Comment: Maybe you have 2 activities and the default screen is set to that Hello world activity, check your Manifest.

Comment: i just have 1 activity which is activity_main

Comment: did you checked it on emulator?

Comment: Check if the xml layout with the EditBox and Button is the one referenced by the `MainActivity` in `onCreate` inside the `setContentView` method. That should solve your issue